# SlickGrid Row selection not working

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I've been trying to implement the possibility to select rows in a SlickGrid for at couple of days now. Slickgrid has a nice example, which I've followed (at least tried to ;):

http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-checkbox-row-select.html

However, the selection checkmarks are not displayed in my own implementation, which runs without any errors showing up in my console (other that a couple of images not found).

I'm baffled and would very much appreciate any help, or pointers in the right direction.

My implementation can be found here:
http://borup.zapto.org/randomstuff/slickgridsort.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox is being created and rendered correctly on the grid. I think there is a conflicting CSS class that is setting the width of the select to 350px.

Please check your styles in the main.css file - line 69. This sets the width of the all input tags, including checkboxes to 350px. I think you will need to overwrite this with the proper width for the grid checkboxes - maybe use a column CSS class.